# Double click on left hand side icon to close window?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, compiz, metacity

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 and if I open a window I want to double click on icon on the left hand side of the window in order to close the window which is the default behavior in Windows.

Comment: should be tagged with: gnome compiz metacity

Comment: I think so too, but the poster should confirm this setup, or that it's the default setup.

Comment: I did not know it was related to compiz metacity

Comment: The default for ubuntu is gnome with metacity, compiz can be enabled easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just yesterday I posted a how-to about this on [my blog](http://linuxandwhatever.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/how-to-make-compizgtk-window-decorator-close-a-window-when-you-double-click-the-upper-left-corner/). It applies to compiz as well as to metacity, but the instructions given are for compiz. I'll sum up what you would need to do here:

- download the sources
- patch them
- make a new deb package
- uninstall the old one, install it instead
- create a new key in gconf

But if this seems too complicated to you, you could always switch to xfce or kde.

Comment: Would be nice if metacity/compiz added a configurable option for this.  It has been requested multiple times in metacity bugzilla but always closed as dup/notabug

Answer (score 1):

There is no configuration setting in Gnome or Compiz that will let you do this. Your best bet is to use the close button and get used to it (benefit: works even on Windows).

Comment: True, there is no config setting. Doesn't mean it can't be done though.

Comment: That's why I didn't say that it couldn't be done.

Comment: Well, I didn't say you said that. Did I? ;)

Comment: No, but it sounded like you did.

Comment: No need to argue

Comment: Sorry, can't resist: Your answer sounded like it couldn't be done.

Comment: We're not arguing, are we? We're having fun. ;)

Comment: Enjoy the fun :-)

Comment: ... while it lasts.